# How to combine and manipulate lists and strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have two lists

```
List1 = ['I','a']
List2 = ['am','programmer']
```

the first output must be like these :

```
['Iam','aprogrammer']
```

the second output must be like these :

```
('IAm','AProgrammer')
```

the third output must be like these :

```
('IAM','APROGRAMMER')
```

in case using list, tuple, and dictionary in python3 for functional programming what should I do to it?

I have tried something like this but my output isn't the same as desired output above :

```
l = list(a for ab in zip(list1, list2) for a in ab)
a=[x.upper() for x in l]
tuple(a) ##but the out put is ('I','AM','A','PROGRAMMER')
b=[x.capitalize() for x in l]
tuple(b) ##but the out put is ('I','Am','A','Programmer')
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried something

Comment: Look at my edited question

Comment: Can you describe in plain English how you would solve the problem by hand?

Comment: Have a look at what `''.join(['a', 'b'])` does. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Can u explain how it's work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used two lists:

```py
list_1 = ['I', 'a']
list_2 = ['am', 'aprogrammer']
```

### First Case

```py
>>> [f'{one}{two}' for one, two in zip(list_1, list_2)]
['Iam', 'aprogrammer']
```

### Second Case

```
>>> [f'{one.capitalize()}{two.capitalize()}' for one, two in zip(list_1, list_2)]
['IAm', 'AProgrammer']
```

### Third Case

```py
>>> [f'{one.upper()}{two.upper()}' for one, two in zip(list_1, list_2)]
['IAM', 'APROGRAMMER']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.join` along with `str.capitalize` and `str.upper`:

```
res1 = tuple(''.join([i,j]) for i,j in zip(List1, List2))
# ('Iam', 'aprogrammer')

res2 = tuple(''.join([i.capitalize(),j.capitalize()]) for i,j in zip(List1, List2))
# ('IAm', 'AProgrammer')

res3 = tuple(''.join([i.upper(),j.upper()]) for i,j in zip(List1, List2))
# ('IAM', 'APROGRAMMER')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you want by using [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) (since you mention functional programming):

```
List1 = ['I','a']
List2 = ['am','programmer']

first = [''.join(pair) for pair in zip(List1, List2)]
second = [''.join(map(str.capitalize, pair)) for pair in zip(List1, List2)]
third = [''.join(map(str.upper, pair)) for pair in zip(List1, List2)]

print(first)
print(second)
print(third)
```

**Output**

```
['Iam', 'aprogrammer']
['IAm', 'AProgrammer']
['IAM', 'APROGRAMMER']
```

For the sake of completeness I include a quote to the documentation on join:

> Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable.

Answer (score 0):

from @Daniel Mesejo @Chris and @Pedro Rodrigues description, I get my answer like these I hope my answer can help someone out there :

**Case 1**

```
case1 = [''.join(pair) for pair in zip(list1, list2)]
```

**Case 2**

```
case2 = tuple([''.join(map(str.capitalize, pair)) for pair in zip(list1, list2)])
```

**Case 3**

```
case3 = tuple([''.join(map(str.upper, pair)) for pair in zip(list1, list2)])
```

**Output**

```
['Iam','aprogrammer']
('IAm','AProgrammer')
('IAM','APROGRAMMER')
```